# nginx: переадресация с одна порта на два

Tags: nginx, https

есть сервер nginx.
у него есть два конфига:

1.server  слушает domain.com:789 ssl

2.client слушае domain.com:889 ssl

Можно ли сделать так что бы те кто спрашивает 
domain.com:888 получали ответ от :789 и :889 в зависимости от того ответ ест или нет.

например:

если мы шлем 
/getList /+какие то данные постом/ :789 ответит, а :889 не сможет

и в свою очередь, если мы шлем
/getScreen /+какие то данные постом/ :889 ответит, а :789 не сможет

Comment: Странное желание. А если оба могут ответить? По хорошему должен быть список адресов по которым отвечает каждый из серверов. Или хотя бы список для одного из них, а на второй отправляются все остальные запросы.

Comment: допустим не могут... речь о том, что есть продукт, который надо поставить.... но продукт имеет имеет сервер на одном порте, а клиент на другом и трогать такое чудо нельзя, и пробросить могут только один порт... вот и возникает вопрос как их можно по одному адресу и порту дергать.